# Python 3.9.1 - Numpy 1.19.4

Tags: pandas, numpy, python-3.9

I have upgraded my Python to use version `3.9.1`. I have installed a module called `Pandas` which requires `Numpy`. Have followed the `pip install` commands and now when I try to import `Pandas`, I am getting an error that `Numpy` installation fails to pass sanity check.

[image]

Comment: Downgrade Python to 3.8.X

Comment: Instead of downgrading a major-version of python as recommended in comments/answers here, you might just read the link available within your screenshot to get a grasp about the problem and workaround-proposals like just downgrading numpy to `1.19.3` (= accepted answer at Michael's comment)

Comment: (I'd prefer a block quote with copy&pasted text over pixel raster renditions.)

Comment: That is wrong advice @k33da_lets_debug, it's easier to downgrade numpy to `1.19.3` instead of you whole python installation.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, discovered that the Numpy team are aware of the problem, you have to downgrade back to Numpy 1.19.3

[Numpy 1.19.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEBez.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use Python 3.8.5. I've had a lot of problems recently regarding 3.9.x compatibility with many modules.

If you're on Anaconda use:

```
conda install python=3.8.5
```